# How can I reference attributes before a save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes, virtual

I have a Reservation model that takes an appointment attribute as `date` and has a virtual attribute `duration` that indicates how long the appointment will take. The real attribute, `booking_end` takes a Time that is referenced all over my application. However, for ease of input, we use duration instead of choosing another `Time`. The fields are below:

```
def duration
  ( (booking_end - date) / 1.hour ).round( 2 ) rescue nil
end

def duration=(temp)
  if ( true if Float(temp) rescue false )
    self.booking_end = time_round(date + temp.to_f.hours, 15.minutes)
  else  
    errors.add(:duration, "must be a number, stated in hours.")
    self.booking_end = nil
  end
end
```

The whole thing fails when I reference the `date` field while creating a new record. I get a 'nil' error because date hasn't been initialized. How can I fix this problem? The rest of this works when updating existing records.

Comment: What value should the `date` attribute default to?

Comment: It defaults to a future date & time in the view. Currently, validations check that it is a valid date & not nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call *Reservation.new(:date => date, :duration => duration)*  ActiveRecord::Base assigns attributes values this way (see assign_attributes method):

```
attributes.each do |k, v|
  ...
  respond_to?("#{k}=") ? send("#{k}="", v) 
  ...
```

*Hash#each* method iterates through the values the way that *:duration* key is accessed before  *:date* one, so *date* is nil inside the *duration=* method:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > {:date => Date.today, :duration => 5}.each do |key,value|
ruby-1.8.7-p302 >     puts "#{key} = #{value}"
ruby-1.8.7-p302 ?>  end
duration = 5
date = 2010-11-17
```

So you'll have to call *duration=* after initialization.

Or you can redefine Reservation#initialize to call super with :date and then update_attributes with the rest of parameters.

Comment: I tried to initialize the model with Reservation.new(params[:reservation][:date])

Comment: See addition about initialize

Answer (score 0):

I tried to initialize the model with

```
Reservation.new(params[:reservation][:date])
```

and then call `update_attributes` on it. This works in console, but not otherwise. The only workaround that seems to take hold is stripping duration out of the params hash and then passing it back before save. This seems really stupid, though, and probably not the right or Rails way to do things. Using 4 lines where one should suffice.

```
duration = params[:reservation][:duration]
params[:reservation].delete('duration')
@reservation = Reservation.new(params[:reservation])
@reservation.duration = duration
# Then go to save, etc.
```

Is there a different way to initialize the model or perhaps access the attributes hash from inside the model?